# Convergence of linear functional on $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $e_i$ is the vector with $1$ at the $i^{th}$ place and $0$ elsewhere for $i=1, 2, ...$. Then $\{f(e_i)\}$ converges for every continuous linear functional on $\ell^2$

My thought: $\vert f(e_i)\vert\leq C \vert \vert e_i \vert \vert_2 \leq C$ but after that I cant make it. Please help

Answer (score 6):

Since $\ell^2$ is an Hilbert space and $f$ is a continuous linear functional, by Bessel's inequality you have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty |f(e_i)|^2 \leq \|f\|^2,
$$
hence $f(e_i) \to 0$.

Comment: Can we claim ${e_i}$ is not convergent in $l^2$ because it is not Cauchy as any two distinct ${e_i}$ sits at a distance of $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Yes, we can claim that.

Comment: Thank you Rigel.

Answer (score 1):

All bounded linear functionals on $\ell^2$ are of the form:

$$f(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_nx_n, \quad\forall (x_1, x_2, \ldots) \in \ell^2$$

for some sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^2$.

Recall that $\ell^2$ is contained in $c_0$, the space of all sequences converging to $0$.

Therefore

$$f(e_i) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n\delta_{ni} = \alpha_i \xrightarrow{i\to\infty} 0$$

because $(\alpha_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$.